# How do you properly reference the viewModel in extended methods when using the knockout.viewmodel plugin?

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-viewmodel-plugin

I'm extending the viewModel.  I need to implement the `addEmployee` method so that it properly references the viewModel.

This is what I have thus far:

JSON:

```
{"Employees":
    [{"FirstName":"James",
      "LastName":"Bond",
      "Addresses":[{"StreetNumber":"MI6","StreetName":"Undisclosed"},
                   {"StreetNumber":"SAS","StreetName":"Undisclosed"}]},
     {"FirstName":"Jason",
      "LastName":"Bourne",
      "Addresses":[{"StreetNumber":"CIA","StreetName":"Undisclosed"},
                   {"StreetNumber":"NSA","StreetName":"Undisclosed"}]}
     ]
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$.getJSON("http://localhost:58191/api/employees", function (jsonModel) {

document.getElementById("test").innerText = JSON.stringify(jsonModel);

var options = {
    extend: {
        "{root}": function () {

            var self = this;
            var employees = new Array();

            self.employees = ko.observableArray(employees);
            var arrayTest = [{ "FirstName": "test", "LastName": "test", "Addresses": [{ "StreetNumber": "MI6", "StreetName": "Undisclosed" }, { "StreetNumber": "SAS", "StreetName": "Undisclosed" }] }];

            self.addEmployee = function () {
                self.employees.push(arrayTest);

            }.bind(self);
        }
    }
}

var kovmmappingVM = ko.viewmodel.fromModel(jsonModel, options);    
ko.applyBindings(kovmmappingVM, document.getElementById("POC"));

});
```

I would appreciate any assistance.  Thanks!

Comment: Does your code throw an error?

Comment: No, it doesn't throw any exceptions.

Comment: And the problem you're having is...

Comment: it doesn't appear to be updating the viewmodel with the new record when i click a button that invokes the addEmployee function.

Comment: my goal is to add a new record to the Employees collection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var kovmmappingVM = ko.viewmodel.fromModel(jsonModel, options);
kovmmappingVM.addEmployee = function (empl) {
    kovmmappingVM.Employees.push(empl);
}
ko.applyBindings(kovmmappingVM, document.getElementById("POC"));
```

Comment: interesting, i'll give it a shot :)

Comment: What about the options param? Did you intend to keep that?

Comment: @user3699387 Depends if you have other options

Comment: You're assistance was instrumental.  I've learning this library so I may reach out to you again for help.  Thanks a lot brother :)

Comment: @user3699387 Well, you could upvote when I answer your questions :) Glad my answers are useful

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
var Employee = function () {

var self = this;    
self.addEmployee = function (kovmmappingVM) {

    kovmmappingVM.Employees.push({
                                    FirstName: "test",
                                    LastName: "test",
                                    Addresses: [{ "StreetNumber": "MI6", "StreetName":   "Undisclosed" }, { "StreetNumber": "SAS", "StreetName": "Undisclosed" }]

                                 });

    model = ko.viewmodel.toModel(kovmmappingVM);
    document.getElementById("test2").innerText = JSON.stringify(model);

    }.bind(self);
}


$.getJSON("http://localhost:58191/api/employees", function (jsonModel) {

    document.getElementById("test").innerText = JSON.stringify(jsonModel);

    var options = {
        extend: {
            "{root}": Employee
        }
    };

    var kovmmappingVM = ko.viewmodel.fromModel(jsonModel, options);   

    ko.applyBindings(kovmmappingVM, document.getElementById("POC"));  
});
```